# Message is localized but message template is not

Tags: message-templates

I received an summary of an activity that looked like this (in Swedish):

| Åtgärdssammanställning - Telefonsamtal |  |
| --- | --- |
| Med kontakt(er) | name_10564 |
| Typ av åtgärd | Telefonsamtal |
| Ämne | Introduktion |

Obviously this is translated, which is kind of good, but the `name_10564` should definitely be a real name.

Problem is that I can't find this template in the System Workflow template list. The only one I find is "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity" and that is using the default template.

How can this be and where should I look for the template for "Activity Summary"?

We're running on Joomla if that (file locations?) are relevant.

(It seems that some of these strings exist in the translation on Transifex, to which I'm partly responsible ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `name_xxx` check your settings at Administer - CiviCase - CiviCase settings. There's a setting called "Redact Activity Email" that changes real names for privacy.

And yes the email template used to send to activity assignees is called "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity" even for regular emails.

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't seen that setting before. And, all types of activity emails are crammed into one template, ok... Need to be really careful if you want to edit it ;-)